# css not working for range input slider

Tags: html, css, slider, range

I want to display the range input slider in "Vertical".

i use this code to display vertical `-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical` it displays the slider but css is not working it showing ordinary inputrange slider.

Can anyone help me how to do that .

this is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;"/>
    <title>How to style an HTML5 range input with CSS</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body {
            font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        input[type='range'] {
            -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical !important;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #333;
            background-color: #157DEC;
            display: block;
            height: 15px;
            left: 10px;
            margin: -100px 0 0 100px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
        }
        input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
            -webkit-appearance:  none !important;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(circular, left top, left bottom, from(##FFFFFF), to(#AAA));
            border: 1px solid #999;
            height: 33px;
            width: 33px;
        }
        #range {
            display: block;
            font-size: 200%;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: -58px -12px 107px 4px ;
            text-align: center;
        }
        p {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 10px;
            font-size: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <span id="range">0</span>
        <input type=range name=salary min="0" max="5" value="0" step="1" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />


    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showValue(newValue) {
            document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't of height in your css. You forcing to a fixed dimension.

here is my suggestion for your style

```
   body {
        font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    input[type='range'] {
        -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;/*comment this to see the result*/
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #333;
        background-color: #157DEC;
        display: block;
        /*height: 15px;*/
        left: 10px;
        /*margin: -100px 0 0 100px;*/
        /*position: absolute;*/
        right: 10px;
        margin-top:50px;
    }
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance:  none !important;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(circular, left top, left bottom, from(##FFFFFF), to(#AAA));
        border: 1px solid #999;
       /* height: 33px;*/
        width: 33px;
    }
    #range {
        display: block;
        font-size: 200%;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: -58px -12px 107px 4px ;
        text-align: center;
    }
    p {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 10px;
        font-size: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

A here is a preview on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QXzLT/